# Why doesn't my pyserial port work in if-statement?

Tags: serial-port, port, pyserial

I can print the "reading" variable, but I can't figure out how to use it in an "if statement". As I said, it prints the string that I am sending from my microbit to my computer, but when I check if the string is == "A", it doesn't print "it works" EKS:

```
import keyboard
import serial.tools.list_ports
ports = serial.tools.list_ports.comports()
serialInst = serial.Serial()

portList = []

for onePort in ports:
        portList.append(str(onePort))
        print(str(onePort))

serialInst.baudrate = 115200
serialInst.port = "COM3"
serialInst.open()

while True:
    if serialInst.in_waiting:
        packet = serialInst.readline().decode('utf-8')
        print(type(packet))
        print(packet)
        if packet == "A":
                print("itworks")
        #print(packet.decode('utf'))
        if keyboard.is_pressed('esc'):
                break
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out:
You have to strip "packet"
So now it looks like this:

```
if packet.strip() == "A":
    print("it works")
```